# Cannot Access Data in Angular Components

Tags: json, mongodb, angular, symfony

problem

> Cannot Access Data from Symfony to Angular2 Component.

what i tried

Angular2 snippet

> dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(public http: Http) {}
    ngOnInit() {

    }
    public persons: any;

    data() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost/api')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.persons = res;
            });
    }

}
```

> dashboard.component.html

```
 <a *ngFor="let person of persons"  [routerLink]="['/detail', hero.id]"  class="col-1-4">
  <div class="module hero">
    <h4>{{person.name}}</h4>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

json data

```
{
 id: "592413bc93d2992800000029",
  name: "A Foo Bar",
 price: 19.99
},
{
 id: "5924145b93d299a812000029",
 name: "A Foo Bar",
 price: 19.99
}
```

- we have backend as symfony2 we are just passing json into component.
- when i tried to print {{persons}} in dashboard.component.html file it doesn't print something.
- can anyone suggest what im missing while rendering data from rest api.
- any suggestion is most welcome.

> i have found problem no Http Request were Triggered in Browser when data() function triggered by angular2 component.

Comment: where do you call the `data` method

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the `data` method. Otherwise, http request will not trigger.

```
constructor(public http: Http) {
   this.data();
}
```

Comment: hi sachin i found there is no xhr request made .can you suggest something

Comment: there is no error i means AJAX REQUEST WAS NOT MADE that's why no data

Comment: yeah u need to call the `data` method inside constructor like i mention in the answer

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the problem

they are 2 issue in in_memory_api or fake-bakend  was main problem

> app.module.ts

```
imports:

 [

   InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
 ]
```

instead try with:

```
 imports:

 [

  InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true}), // fake in memory API simulation
 ]
```

if you use fake provider

```
 providers: [
 fakeBackendProvider,//comment this,if you use this xhr request would go 404
 ]
```

> service.ts

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});

private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost/api';  

getApiData(): Promise<ApiDashboard[]> {
            return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json() as ApiDashboard[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
             }
```

try these step im sure this will works if http request gets 404.

Answer (score -2):

Also it seems your router link is wrong in the HTML. SHouldn't it be 
[routerLink]="['/detail', **person**.id]" ?

Comment: rohit can you tell why http request does triggered  in browser when data function triggered